# Nand2tetris hardware simulator GUI not opening

Tags: nand2tetris

Hi This question may not belong on this forum but I'm not sure where else to post it. I'm taking the Nand2Tetris course and in week 1 the instructor goes through the Hardware Simulator to test HDL code. The instructor shows a GUI. Trouble is when I try to follow along and I click on the HDL simulator.Sh file. I don't get an GUI I just get a list of apps to open my code the best being VS code which doesn't seems to run HDL. Anyone here familiar with Nand2 Tetris and knows how I can get the HDL simulator (preferably with the GUI) to work?

Comment: Likely the problem is that you do not have Java installed on your computer - the Nand2Tetris emulators are all Java apps. You can find the Java installer here: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: Other possible problems: You want to execute a SHell script. Start it from a shell=terminal, chmod it +x.

Comment: Java is installed on my computer. Sebastian I understand you are saying to start it from a command prompt but what do you mean by chmod it +x

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Under Linux like permission systems you have to make a file executable before you can run it. This can be done with chmod +x filename. A shell script .sh must be executable. If you are using Windows, you probably have to manually convert the .sh to a .bat file. It will be short enough and just contain commands to set environment variables and start Java for the simulator.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. Now it works